# How to align items in different rows of ItemsControl? (Silverlight)

Tags: c#, silverlight

How to align items in different rows of ItemsControl?

Comment: can you expand on your question a little bit? Maybe an example?

Comment: Can you use fixed-size columns, or does it have to depend on the items in the control?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <ItemsControl>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="Right alignment"></TextBox>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Left alignment"></TextBox>
    </ItemsControl>
```